# Trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on an old PC does not load Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, installation

I'm not new in Ubuntu, but I'm trying to install Ubuntu on another computer (my sister's PC), but when I configure BIOS to load from optical drive, it never loads.

Actually, Windows loads!

Comment: Is there any other os pre installed?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, first try to load that Ubuntu CD in another computer to discard the optical drive. Also, if your sister's computer allows booting from USB you could try that option too.

Comment: well, there is windows 7 pre installed, and also i have already tried installing with this cd in my laptop.So?

Comment: I mean, if you can try that is not the CD you're using that is not good or if it is not a hardware problem of your  sister's computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can boot from your Ubuntu CD on another PC, it seems to be a BIOS or CD-ROM matter. So, you have two options:

- try to make the PC boot from CD - re-check if the BIOS has the required boot order, or try to open the boot device menu that's usually available besides the BIOS (with AMI BIOS: called `BBS POPUP`, activate by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> during boot).
- try to use another boot device - a USB stick, for example (again, make sure that booting from USB is enabled in the BIOS and that the boot order is set appropriately).

Answer (score 1):

Some old motherboards have a nasty habit of loading the first ready disk they see even if you tell it to boot from the CD drive.

Try to press the <kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd> button during POST (its the first screen you see before the OS actually starts loading) inserting the CD in to the drive and press enter only when the drive's LED stops blinking.

Other than that I can only imagine 3 things: BIOS still not properly configured, defective CD drive or something went wrong when you burned the CD with Ubuntu into it.

You can also check your BIOS and see if you have a *Boot from USB drive* option and create a bootable USB pen with Ubuntu in it, for that follow the instruction in point number 2 (*Burn your CD or create a bootable USB stick*) in the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

Answer (score -1):

It's KMS  issue. Newer ubuntu searching for perfect graphics driver on load. Disable it

```
1. In ubuntu installation menu(Try ubuntu, install ubuntu ..) press F6
2. select nomodeset( a "x" will show when select)
3. Now select install ubuntu or try ubuntu without install
```

Comment: maybe i dont understand,but i cannot reach my ubuntu installation.Automatically the pc is loading windows!